# WebStorm: Foundation project won't compile default SCSS files

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, webstorm

I tried to make a Foundation project in WebStorm tonight, but I couldn't seem to compile the SCSS files that the Foundation framework delivers. But whenever I make an SCSS file myself, even in the directories of the Foundation SCSS files, they will be compiled.

How can I make the files become compiled?

Comment: Please provide some more info, for example your code where you try to include the Foundation Sites Sass.

Comment: I fixed the problem. The problem was this: I openend a new Foundation project in WebStorm and it cloned the whole Foundation repo. It didn't bring in some sample HTML (as far a I saw) so I didn't know how to call in the Foundation framework in my HTML. I expected that I had to link to /scss/foundation.css. It didn't work and I saw that many of the files in /scss were not compiled. Later that night, I discovered that I had to link to /assets/foundation.css and that the files that weren't compiled didn't have to be compiled (they all began with an underscore). Now my project works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem: I thought that the CSS file I had to link to in my HTML was at `/scss/foundation.css`. This did not work, so I thought that the problem was that some SCSS files weren't compiled. In reality, I should have linked to `assets/foundation.css`. When I did that, my Foundation worked as it should. So the problem was not that my IDE didn't compile my SCSS files, but that I linked to the wrong CSS file.